# Screen flickering on login attempt

Tags: boot, updates, screen, amd-graphics, login-screen

Yesterday I had an update, today when something weird is happening, when the machine boots it all seems fine  but when I reach the login screen the screen glitches and flickers, it's completely unusable.

I have tried booting on windows and it works fine, what could be the problem?

EDIT: further information, I'm running 22.04 LTS in a Lenovo IdeaPad laptop with integrated graphics card, I update from the terminal at least once a week but the updates I'm taking about came from the update manager that automatically appeared yesterday with an update for Ubuntu base

I have tried using the recovery mode but I don't think I know how to make it do what I want, trying out some of the graphics options it just brings back the same menu over and over, when finally hitting run it gets stuck on a black screen with a blinking cursor but after a few minutes nothing changes, no text, no movement, no sound from the fan ir the drive

Comment: You've provided few specific details; what OS/release are you using?  If it's a LTS release, I'd be interested for example how often you apply your updates (*daily? weekly? etc*) as that may provide clues as to what upgrades you're asking about. Currently we have no ideas, and in recent days I can't think of any significant changes (*but you may upgrade less than daily & thus a longer period for your unstated release needs to be considered*). What DM or *display manager* are you using (ie. what greeter!)? as you've not told us what that is.

Comment: further information, I'm running 22.04 LTS in a Lenovo IdeaPad laptop with integrated graphics card, I update from the terminal at least once a week but the updates I'm taking about came from the update manager that automatically appeared yesterday with an update for Ubuntu base.

Comment: I don't know what display Manager I have, I remember a few months ago on a update some packages said something about Wayland and others said something about xorg, I don't know if this has anything to do with it

Comment: We can provide more details if you're specific; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is the 2022-April release of Ubuntu, it's available as a Server system, Desktop system, as well as many *flavors*. You've not said which you are using, only provide your release as 22.04; where the install media dictates which kernel you're using (Server install defaults to GA, Desktop to HWE, *flavors* specific to media used for 22.04). Weekly updating though wouldn't be kernel change (5.19 to 6.2 if using HWE was many weeks ago now), and Xorg vs Wayland doesn't really impact the greeter/login/DM only after it (ie. sessions)